# Unrecognized selector sent to instance in Tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

Ok I am trying to create a simple TableView app that when the row is selected, transitions to a WebView. I am using story boards and do have my links connected properly. I am getting an error like the one below. I have been following tutorials off Lynda.com and also one from [appcoda.com](http://www.appcoda.com/improve-detail-view-controller-storyboard-segue/%22appcoda.com%22) and both use the methods I have tried below by using "Guide" or whatever the title of their class with NSObject is. I am really puzzled and confused as I can not figure out why it won't recognize it. I have tried deleting the @property (nonatomic, strong) Guide *html; part but still get the same message. I hope this is specific enough for you. Oh I am using the latest version of xcode.

My error message is

```
-[Guide isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8543aa0
2013-05-05 11:33:29.076 hikingHelp[5522:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception    NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Guide isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector 
sent to instance 0x8543aa0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

My Guide.h file is below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "MapViewController.h"


@interface Guide : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *htmlListName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *htmlFileName;

@end
```

My TableViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Guide.h"

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController
{
NSMutableArray *htmlFiles;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) Guide *html;
@end
```

My TableViewController.m in the -(void)viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

htmlFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Guide *html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Survival Planning"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"survivalplanning.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];

html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Survival Kits"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"survivalkits.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];

html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Basic Survivl Medicine"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"basichealth.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];

html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Shelters"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"shelters.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];

html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Water Procurement"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"waterprocurement.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];

html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Firecraft"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"firecraft.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];

html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Food"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"food.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];

html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Edible Plants"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"edibleplant.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];

html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Posionous Plants"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"posionousplants.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];

html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Dangerous Animals"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"dangerousanimals.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];

html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Water Crossing"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"watercrossings.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];

html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Find Directions"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"directions.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];

html = [[Guide alloc] init];
[html setHtmlListName:@"Signaling Techniques"];
[html setHtmlFileName:@"signaling.html"];
[htmlFiles addObject:html];
```

Comment: Where is your UITableView code and are you checking `isEqualToString` anywhere.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the exception? None of the code you posted is causing the error.

Comment: *Do you even for loop bro?* Get two NSArrays, one for the htmlListName (NSStrings), and another for the htmlFileName. Loop through one of the arrays, and create an instance of Guide, adding it to the array each time.

Comment: Where is your Guide.m ? Please post your Guide.m code here.

Comment: @max Just starting out so no I never thought about using a for loop. Just trying to go off of some tutorials to get the basics while making my own version of the app.

Comment: @Thilina Guide.m is just the same but sythisized so didn't think I should post it.

Comment: @rmaddy I get the exception on the '@property (strong, nonatomic) Guide *html;' and no I am not checking 'isEqualToString' anywhere.

Comment: Are you calling `[[htmlFiles objectAtIndex:someIndex] isEqualToString:...]` or `[htmlFiles[index] isEqualToString:..]`? Alternatively are you storing NSStrings in that array too? Contrary (I'm running out of connectives) are you trying to call `[html.htmlFileName isEqualToString:...]` and instead running `[html isEqualToString]`?

Comment: @max_ No I am not calling any of those. I would post my whole code but I know that would be exhausting for you all even though its not that much. I am going back through some tutorials, and then attempting to replicate them without looking. Until I can write a table app without having to look I am just going to put this project on the side. Thanks for you help and input though. I can't wait to be able to get this down and help others!

Comment: @max_ you know a second hard look and your right! I am calling 'htmlFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row' in the cell ForRowAtIndexPath. 

My code is 'cell.textLabel.text = [ htmlFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];'

I have it as it should populate my array that I set up earlier.

Comment: @kenthub there's the problem. You need to be using `[[htmlFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] htmlFileName];` Also, use backticks for code - `

Comment: @kenthub I've added my answer with the solution. Accept it if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is arising because you are retrieving the Guide instance from the array, thinking you are receiving the `htmlFileName` or `htmlListName` in your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Instead of using `cell.textLabel.text = [htmlFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`, use the following:

```
Guide *rowGuide = htmlFiles[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = rowGuide.htmlFileName;
```

Also, instead of manually setting instantiating each of the Guide instances in your `-viewDidLoad` method, you can use a for loop or alternatively NSFastEnumeration:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    htmlFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *htmlListNames = @[@"Survival Planning", @"Survival Kits", @"Basic Survivl Medicine", @"Shelters", @"Water Procurement", @"Firecraft", @"Food", @"Edible Plants", @"Poisonous Plants", @"Dangerous Animals", @"Water Crossing", @"Find Directions", @"Signalling Technique"];
    NSArray *htmlFileNames = @[@"survivalplanning.html", @"survivalkits.html", @"basichealth.html", @"shelters.html", @"waterprocurement.html", @"firecraft.html", @"food.html", @"edibleplant.html", @"posionousplants.html", @"dangerousanimals.html", @"watercrossings.html", @"directions.html", @"signaling.html"];

    for (NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < [htmlListNames count]; idx++) {
        Guide *guide = [[Guide alloc] init];
        [guide setHtmlListName:htmlListNames[idx]];
        [guide setHtmlFileName:htmlFileNames[idx]];
        [htmlFiles addObject:guide];
        [guide release]; // if you're not using arc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Also I was going to google how to set up the array in a for loop so thanks for taking care of that also!

Answer (score 0):

```
-[Guide isEqualToString:]
```

Guide is a class it is not a string so how can it compare a class to a string.

Comment: a string is a class too ... you got the issue right but your answer isnt formulated correctly

Comment: Guide is subClass of NSObject you can [guideObj.htmlFileName isEqualToString:@"Matchedstring"];

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method `isEqualToString:` which is defined on NSString instances on your custom object of type `Guide` somewhere

As the class Guide isEqualToString: you get an error.

- EITHER you somewhere mistakenly work with a Guide assuming it is a strong
- OR you pass some method (maybe from the tableView dataSource) a Guide and IT normally assumes a string